# Unhandle when database NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext();   
var TMACost = (from emp in db.Incomes where emp.Time > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1) select emp.Cost).Sum();    
Label15.Text = TMACost.ToString();
```

I want to sum value in database but can't run when database is empty ,any idea?

Comment: When database is empty you have nothing to sum. So just don't sum anything. Being serious - please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask a good question here.

Comment: select new {cost = emp.Cost ?? 0;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cast to a nullable number. This will return null when the table is empty. Then, you can use the coalesce operator:

```
var TMACost = (
    from emp in db.Incomes 
    where emp.Time > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1) 
    select (decimal?) emp.Cost
    ).Sum() ?? 0m;
```

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to sum a value that might return null, so just check if its null before summing

```
DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext();   
var TMACost = (from emp in db.Incomes where emp.Time > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1) select emp.Cost); 
Label15.Text = (TMACost.length!=DBNull.Value)?TMACost.Sum().ToString():"0";
```

Comment: Your code won't even compile. And if you used .Count() instead of length, you would issue two separate DB requests. If this isn't done inside a transaction, the code is *incorrect* and could produce wrong results if somebody writes to the db in the meantime.